# Dealing with loops in this specific question

Tags: java

I have this question:

There are three types of robot.

i.) Robot A can recycle 16 used bottles - There are 20 Robot As.

ii.) Robot B can recycle 32 used bottles - There are 32 robots B.

iii.) Robot C can recycle 128 used bottles - There are 128 robots C.

I need to calculate the minimum number of robots that are needed to recycle n bottles and print out this number.

So I have decided to use a separate method to call to print out this number:

```
public class Q7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        recycleBottles(16);

    }

    public static void recycleBottles(int n) {

        final int noOfAntrimRobots = 20;
        final int noOfBelfastRobots = 10;
        final int noOfCarrickfergusRobots = 3;

        final int antrimRobotCapacity = 16;
        final int belfastRobotCapacity = 32;
        final int carrickfergusRobotCapacity = 128;

        if (n % antrimRobotCapacity == 0 && n / antrimRobotCapacity <= noOfAntrimRobots) {  // TO check if the bottles if completely divisible by Antrim robots and then print out the number of bottles
            System.out.print("Number of Antrim Robots required: " + (n / antrimRobotCapacity));
        } else if (n % belfastRobotCapacity == 0 && n / belfastRobotCapacity <= noOfBelfastRobots) {
            System.out.print("Number of Belfast Robots required: " + (n / belfastRobotCapacity)); // TO check if the bottles if completely divisible by Belfast robots and then print out the number of bottles
        } else if (n % carrickfergusRobotCapacity == 0 && n / carrickfergusRobotCapacity <= noOfCarrickfergusRobots) { // TO check if the bottles if completely divisible by Carrick Fergus robots and then print out the number of bottles
            System.out.print("Number of Carrick Fergus Robots required: " + (n / carrickfergusRobotCapacity));
        } else {

        if (n > 128) {
            int resultNum = 0;

            while (n/128 < 4) {
                resultNum = resultNum + (n/128);
            }



        }



        }

    }


}
```

I'm stuck on the part where the number is not a multiple of 16, 32 or 128. So far I'm trying to see if bottles are more than 128, then to check if no. of robot for 128 is not more than 3 and then deduct the amount of bottles, to just proceed with other robots.

I'm really stuck in this stage and I'd really help if someone can give me a kickstart at this stage. I've spent hours figuring out but it's been of no avail. I just need a clue to go further.

Comment: I suggest you first figure out how to answer the question yourself with paper and pencil. If you can't do it by hand, there's no way you can program it. If I ask you the min number of robots needed to recycle 3000 bottles what would you do?

Comment: You probably should read how to ask a question about homework: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: you don't remove the question once it is answered ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

1. First check the count of bottles is less than the recycle volume of each robot.

   - If it is less than 16 do it with one robot A
   - If it is greater than 16 and less than 32 do it with robot B
   - If it is greater than 32 and less than 128 do it with robot C
2. If it is greater than 128 then first do it with robot Cs then do Step 1. again
   until the Cs run out.
   Then do this step with robot Bs and after finishing robot Bs try it with robot As.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a case of dividing from greatest

```
    int num = 2340;
    int robC = num / 128;
    num -= robC * 128;
    int robB = num / 32;
    num -= robB * 32;
    int robA = num / 16;
    num -= robA * 16;
    if (num > 0) robA++;
    
    System.out.println(robC);
    System.out.println(robB);
    System.out.println(robA);
```